# Differentiate $x^Tx\cdot x$: scalar v.s. 1-by-1 matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, jacobian

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $y=x^Tx\cdot x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I try to find the differential of y:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}y &= \mathrm{d}x^Tx\cdot x + x^Tx\cdot \mathrm{d}x \\
            &= (\mathrm{d}x^T)x\cdot x + x^T\mathrm{d}x\cdot x + x^Tx\cdot \mathrm{d}x \\
            &= \bigl((\mathrm{d}x^T)x\bigr)^T \cdot x + x^T\mathrm{d}x\cdot x + x^Tx\cdot \mathrm{d}x \\
            &= 2x^T\mathrm{d}x\cdot x + x^Tx\cdot \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

…which looks strange to me, because in the first term, $\mathrm{d}x$ and $x$ are both in $ \mathbb{R}^n$, and yet they are multiplied together. Noticing that this happens in the original $y$ as well, I realize the issue lies in the ambiguity of $x^Tx$ (scalar or a 1-by-1 matrix?), so I try to circumvent this with trace (let $y=tr(x^Tx)\cdot x$):

\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}y &= \mathrm{d}tr(x^Tx)\cdot x + tr(x^Tx)\mathrm{d}x \\
            &= tr(\mathrm{d}x^Tx)x + tr(x^Tx)\mathrm{d}x \\
            &= 2tr(x^T\mathrm{d}x)x + tr(x^Tx)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

This seems right, but I don't know how to proceed.

What am I missing?

Comment: In the same way that we often freely switch between the natural number $2$, the integer $2$, the real number $2$, the complex number $2$ etc... there are often times where we might choose to freely switch between $1\times 1$ matrices whose entry is $a$ and the scalar number $a$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: understood. Still I don't know how to proceed with the first derivation, when taking $x^T\mathrm{d}x$ as a whole scalar.

Comment: @Arthur: Ha, check out the sentence following it.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: If you want to write $y$ as a matrix product, it's still possible: $y=xx^Tx$, i.e. you pace the $1\times1$ matrix on the right ($n\times1$ times $1\times1$ is dimensionally correct, with the usual convention that a vector is equivalent to a column-matrix). For ways to differentiate w.r.t a vector, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend Jean-ClaudeArbaut's comment.

Write your function in a form which is valid whether $x$ is a vector or a matrix
$$y=xx^Tx \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$$
Then differentiate
$$\dot y = \dot x\,x^Tx + x\dot x^Tx + xx^T\dot x$$
Finally, take advantage of vector properties which aid factorization
$$\dot y = \Big[(x^Tx)I + 2xx^T\Big]\dot x\qquad$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing a couple more parentheses might be useful. In particular, in the first solution you write, in the final line, when $2x^T\mathrm{d}x\cdot x$ is written, what is meant is $$2(x^T\mathrm{d}x)\cdot x.$$ In the expression, $x$ and $\mathrm dx$ are *not* multiplied together. Instead, you get $x$, multiplied by the *scalar* $x^T\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Right, I understand that this is the case, but still I don't know how to proceed to get $\mathrm{d}x$ out of the scalar. The tools I'm familiar with don't help me with scalar multiplication. (I guess if better phrased, my question would ask this directly, rather than being about scalar vs 1-by-1 matrix.)

Comment: @clearwat you don't get it out of the scalar. Once you calculate it you take the inner product with $x$ to get the scalar.

Comment: @clearwat You know what $x$ is, and you know what $\mathrm{d}x$ is, and then you just calculate $x^T \mathrm dx$. There is no "getting it out of the scalar".

Answer (score 0):

You can $\mathbf{y} =
= \| \mathbf{x} \|^2 \mathbf{x}$
, a scalar times a vector.
Using product rule, you have
$$d\mathbf{y}=(d\| \mathbf{x} \|^2)\mathbf{x}+\| \mathbf{x} \|^2 d\mathbf{x}$$
It is easy to see that
$d\| \mathbf{x} \|^2 =  2 \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}$

Finally it holds
$$
d\mathbf{y}
=2\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x})+\| \mathbf{x} \|^2 d\mathbf{x}
=\left[2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T+\| \mathbf{x} \|^2 \mathbf{I} \right] d\mathbf{x}
$$
The bracket term is the Jacobian matrix you are looking at